# In the case of a tie, how do I return the largest and most frequent number in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of numbers. I created this frequency dictionary d:

```
from collections import Counter
mylist = [10, 8, 12, 7, 8, 8, 6, 4, 10, 12, 10, 12]
d = Counter(mylist)
print(d)
```

The output is like this:

```
Counter({10: 3, 8: 3, 12: 3, 7: 1, 6: 1, 4: 1})
```

I know I can use **max(d, key=d.get)** to get value if there is no tie in frequency. If multiple items are maximal, the function usually returns the first one encountered. How can I return the largest number, in this case, 12, instead of 10?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: FWIW doing `max(d, key=d.get)` when `d` is a `Counter` object beats the purpose. You can do `d.most_common(1)[0][0]`

Comment: @DeepSpace When I tried your solution, I got `10` which is what OP was already getting.

Comment: @mypetlion I did not attempt to answer the question (otherwise I'd have posted an answer, not a comment). I was just pointing out that OP is using `Counter` but not using the tools it provides

Comment: @ FWIW   Thank you. I thought about using most_common(), but could not get parameter right.

Answer (score 1):

Define a lambda function that returns a tuple. Tuples are sorted by their first value, and then tie-broken by subsequent values. Like this:

```
max(d, key=lambda x:(d.get(x), x))
```

So for the two example values, the lambda will return `(3, 10)` and `(3, 12)`. And of course, the second will be considered the `max`.

Further explanation:

When the `max` function is given a collection to find the max of, and a `key`, it will go over the values in the collection, passing each value into the `key` function. Whatever element from the collection results in the maximal output from the `key` function is considered the maximal value.

In this case, we're giving it a lambda function. Lambdas are just functions. Literally no difference in their usage, just a different syntax for defining them. The above example could have been written as:

```
def maxKey(x):return (d.get(x), x)
max(d, key=maxKey)
```

and it would behave the same way.

Using that function, we can see the return values that it would give for your sample data.

```
maxKey(10) #(3, 10)
maxKey(12) #(3, 12)
```

The main difference between the anonymous lambda above and using `d.get` is that the lambda returns a `tuple` with two values in it.

When `max` encounters a tie, it returns the first one it saw. But because we're now returning `tuple`s, and because we know that the second value in each `tuple` is unique (because it comes from a dictionary), we can be sure that there won't be any duplicates. When `max` encounters a `tuple` it first compares the first value in the `tuple` against whatever it has already found to be the maximal value. If there's a tie there, it compares the next value. If there's a tie there, the next value, etc. So when `max` compares `(3, 10)` with `(3, 12)` it will see that `(3, 12)` is the maximal value. Since that is the value that resulted from `12` going into the `key` function, `max` will see `12` as the maximal value.

Comment: @mypetition Sorry I searched a couple of hours trying to understand your code on my own. I could not understand why key=lambda x:(d.get(x), x) here. Are you trying to sort the key or trying to get a maximal number of the keys? Sorry I am still very new to python. I knew little bit of simple lambda in-line funtion. And I tried to break down your code into simple steps but still could not understand it. :(

Comment: @mypetition Thank you!! The last paraph really explains my confusion---max() encounters a tuple when there is a tie.  I really appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the max count (using `d.most_common`), and then get the `max` of all keys that have the max count:

```
max_cnt = d.most_common(1)[0][1]
grt_max = max(n for n, cnt in d.items() if cnt == max_cnt)
print(grt_max)
```

Output:

```
12
```

Comment: Thank you. I thought about using most_common(). But I didn't know I need to set at most_common(1), not 2 or 3.  In this case, there are 3 items tied, But they still considered as top 1? Therefore, most_common(1)?

Comment: @YiDykstra I used `most_common` to get the max count (you could use `max(d.values())` instead), the number you pass to `most_common` is how many elements you want it to return, if you don't pass anything to it, it will return all elements sorted with count.